# Laravel 5: php artisan migrate | Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-artisan

I am trying to run the following command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I receive the following response from the server:

```
HP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#3 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#4 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/la in /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 87
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#3 /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErro in /var/www/stagaires/bart/laravel2/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 87
```

The permissions on the storage and bootstrap folder is 755, also tried 777 but didn't work.

Why does my migrate command not work?

Answer (score 6):

try

```
 chmod -R 777 storage
```

My guess is you didnt make it recursive

Comment: Found it, made it recursive. But it was telling me that I had no permissions to change these settings. The Sudo did the trick. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we had "#" in mysql user's password. that special character was not allowed. we changed the password and issue got resolved. :O